# Use Mathematica LaTeX typesetting for a TextGrid or TableForm

Tags: tables

In Mathematica I can create reasonable Tables which I would then like to insert in a tex document. This works for equations.  However, this does not seem to work for TextGrid and TableForm.

In Mathematica the following code produces this table

```
TextGrid[{
  {"Natural frequency = 10 Hz", "Damping ratio (\[Zeta]) = 0.05"},
  {"Nonlinear parameter (\[Beta]) = 1000", 
   "Sample rate = 5000 samples/s"}
  }]
```

[image]

I can convert this to TeX using the code

```
TeXForm@HoldForm@TextGrid[{
    {"Natural frequency  10 Hz", "Damping ratio (\[Zeta])  0.05"},
    {"Nonlinear parameter (\[Beta])  1000", 
     "Sample rate  5000 samples/s"}
    }]
```

[image]

However, when I paste this into a tex document it does not give me the table. Here is the tex document I used.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Natural frequency = 10 Hz} & \text{Damping ratio ($\zeta $) = 0.05} \\
 \text{Nonlinear parameter ($\beta $) = 1000} & \text{Sample rate = 5000 samples/s} \\
\end{array}

\end{document}
```

It gives me the error

[image]

Is Mathematica missing some code to make this work or am I missing some code?
Thanks

**Edit with answer**

David Carlisle has given a answer in the comments. The answer is that you need to add some extra lines in the TeX code as follows

```
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Natural frequency = 10 Hz} & \text{Damping ratio ($\zeta $) = 0.05} \\
 \text{Nonlinear parameter ($\beta $) = 1000} & \text{Sample rate = 5000 samples/s} \\
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
```

Thus the mathematica TeX should be wrapped as follows with the `\begin{displaymath}`  and finish with the `\end{displaymath}`. Clearly I have plenty to learn here!

Comment: array has to be  in math mode so `\[ \begin{array}..... \]`

Comment: @campa tabular is logically better but just wrapping the mathematica output in math is easier